# Entity Framework 5: Using DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed option

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have an EF5 code first project that uses the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` attribute.
This option is overriding my settings.

Consider this SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicle (
  VehicleId  int identity(1,1) not null,
  Name varchar(100) not null default ('Not Set')
)
```

I am using the SQL default construct to set the [Name] is case it is not set.

In code behind, I have a class defined similar to:

```
public class Vehicle {
   ...

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string ShoulderYN { get; set; }
}
```

When I update the entity in code, the value set in the default overrides my new setting.

In code, I have (pseudo):

```
vehicle.Name = 'Update Name of Vehicle';
_dbContext.Update(vehicle);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The expected result is `Vehicle.Name = 'Update Name of Vehicle'`.
The actual result is `Vehicle.Name = 'Not Set'`.

Is there a way in EF5 to say:
*if Vehicle.Name is null/empty, use the value defined in the database?  Otherwise, if I set the value in code, I want to use this value.*

Answer (score 17):

Apparently, no there isn't. It's not that smart :)

As you may already read, Computed option just tells the EF not to  update your column, because you will compute a value on the DB-side yourself. EF will then just return newly computed value from your database (which in your case is "Not Set").

Your basic three options are - as per EF Source code documentation:

- None - The database does not generate values.
- Identity - The database generates a value when a row is inserted.
- Computed - The database generates a value when a row is inserted or updated.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/527ae18fe23f7649712e9461de0c90ed67c3dca9/src/EntityFramework/DataAnnotations/Schema/DatabaseGeneratedOption.cs

Since you expect a little more custom logic to be done, I'm afraid you would have to do it yourself. I would suggest you stop relying on database default constraint and do everything in code first approach. This way you would have a code like that:

```
public class Vehicle
{
  public Vehicle()
  {
    this.Name = "Not set";
  }
  
  // Without 'Generated' attribute
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This way, when your Entity is created, it automatically starts with expected default value. And can be later changed by simply modifying the Name property.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a simple solution for this:

- You need to leave default constraint with value in table creation script as it is now:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE Vehicle (
    VehicleId  int identity(1,1) not null,
    Name varchar(100) not null default ('Not Set')
  )
  ```
- Just remove `DatabaseGenerated` attribute from property in class definition:

  ```
  public class Vehicle {
     ...

     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
     public string ShoulderYN { get; set; }
  }
  ```

And that's it: now database will use default value only if you do not specify some value in code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why this behavior isnt provided by default? What is the benefit behind this? For example I determine the default date(notnull) in a column of table in DB. But EF send a min datetime if no value send by code. I really cannot find any logic in it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this for hours to get good answer but no: 
EF cannot update models by automatic generated-ID.

You have 3 options:

1. Adding another VehicleId to Vehicle model.
2. Change automatic generated-ID to be manual generated by you.
3. Setting unique identifier to be something else then the generated-ID in your
   model.
   In your Vehicle Class it can be the Name property.

I suggest you option 3: 
Setting up unique-id to be Vehicle.Name (and you can add more properties).
Then: if vehicle by unique-id doesn't exists, add new vehicle to db-context:

```
//if there is no such a Vehicle in system, add it:
if (vehicle.Name !=null && vehicle.Name != String.Empty && _dbContext.Where(v => v.Name == vehicle.Name).FirstOrDefault() == null)
    _dbContext.Add(vehicle);

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```