# EF Core GUID Database Generated in Abstract base class

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

So my entities inherit from a class like this:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public Guid UuId { get; set; }

  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Timestamp]
  public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

The `Key` Id field works fine, Uuid on any insert is always `NULL`.  I've tried adding in:

```
builder.Entity<Series>().Property(x => x.UuId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Doesn't work.

I've since adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` I've tried creating and applying a new migration.

This also doesn't work.

I've tried adding in this to my `EntityBase` class:

```
public Guid UuId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
```

As the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add) say:

> A property is considered to have a value assigned if it is not
>   assigned the CLR default value (null for string, 0 for int, Guid.Empty
>   for Guid, etc.).

What am I missing?  How can  I get this auto generation working?

Comment: Why having Id (primary key) and UUid? Those two properties are auto-generated so unique.

Comment: Down to a requirement.

Comment: So I will remove Id property and use UUid as primary key. By default GUID will be automatically generated by the database without configuring it in EF.

Comment: I need both fields.

Comment: So you just want an auto generated GUID value?

Comment: Indeed.  Rather than litter the code with `Uuid = Guid.NewGuid()` makes sense to hand this off the database.

Comment: @Jammer then just add in your entity configuration this `HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()")`  just after `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`

Comment: I did just that

Comment: Strange that none of the docs suggest that this is the way to get it to work ...

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600556/entity-framework-5-using-databasegeneratedoption-computed-option)'s a good discussion that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

So after all the trial and error the only solution that appears to work is:

```
builder.Entity<Series>().Property(x => x.UuId).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
```

Even though the docs for EF Core doesn't suggest this.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: do you need them to be in order i.e. NEWSEQUENTIALID() instead of NEWID().  NEWID can create hotspots

Comment: Good comment, fortunately we are only using these GUIDs as identifiers rather than anything that requires sequential values. Also the data volume is going to be pretty low.