# Getting the result of a computed column from database into an entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

In a project using Entity Framework, say I have an entity such as

```
[Table("MyTable")]
public partial class MyTable
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Where the `FullName` is computed on a SQL Server 2012 database as a concatenation of `FirstName` and `LastName`.

At the start of the project this entire table is completely loaded locally. That is, via `DbContext.DbSet<MyTable>.Load()`

At run-time I am

1. Creating an instance of this in code
2. Setting the First and Last Name properties of this object.
3. Adding this instance to the `DbSet` of the `DbContext`
4. Calling `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

Now, after the call to `SaveChanges()` I was expecting the `FullName` computed property of the entity to be populated with the computed value. But sadly, this doesn't appear to be happening?

How can I get the computed value from the database into my entity object?

Comment: [Maybe this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600556/entity-framework-5-using-databasegeneratedoption-computed-option). Alternatively you could add an `NotMapped` attribute (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMappedAttribute) to your `FullName` and change it's setter to something like `get { return $"{this.LastName}, {this.FirstName}"; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where the `FullName` is computed on a SQL Server 2012 database as a
>   concatenation of `FirstName` and `LastName`.

Well, you didn't concatenate them into the `FullName` property in your class, since you are using EF-Code First, so you should specify it in your getter, something like this:

```
get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
```

Or with newer version of C#, you can:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
```

Comment: Hi, I was hoping that I would not need to duplicate the logic from the database. Are you saying that Entity Framework doesn't offer the facility to get back the computed values?

Comment: @Cleve Well, you are using EF-Code First. How would you expect that it knows what you mean by `FullName`?

Comment: I was expecting EF to marshal back the calculated value from the database. That's how I expected it to know what FullName is.

Comment: @Cleve could you explain "I was hoping that I would not need to duplicate the logic from the database"...? I don't see the logic anywhere in your question.

Comment: @gldraphael , The logic for calculating the FullName is on the database. If I was to adopt the suggestions above by putting in the concatenation logic into the FullName property of my class then this logic would be in the class AND on the database. Duplicated.

Comment: @Cleve You have mentioned that you are using EF-Code First, so your database will be generated from your classes and you don't have a database already! This is how Code-First works.

Comment: @S.Akbari, my apologies then. I have used the wrong phrase. My scenario is that the database is not generated from my classes. It already exists. The classes serve to model what is on the database. Does this help with my original question?

Comment: @Cleve So I think the duplication will be allowed in your case, as the database will not generate the computed column in your models.

Comment: @S.Akbari, sorry for delayed reply. What's confusing me is that things like navigation properties on my entities get updated when their related id's change so I was assuming that the computed column fields would do also. But you are saying that doesn't happen. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @S.Akbari, sorry for late reply in acknowledging your help. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't duplicate the logic in the database and in the class. What you're probably missing is the instruction to EF Core that the value is generated in the database. Use `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` in your `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>()
    .Property(t => t.FullName)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```